# Find the bottom position of a dynamic control

Tags: vba, excel

In my userform I ask the user how many listboxs they require and based on the number that the user enters the controls are dynamically created during run time. I want to be able to set the size of my userform based on the bottom position of the last dynamic control that was added to the userform. Below shows the code that I have written to do this, all I want to do at the minute is alert the bottom position of each dynamic control as they are added to the user form.

```
Dim dynamicControl As Control

For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
    Set cList = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
    With cList
       .Name = "listbox" & (i)
       .Left = 150
       .Top = listStartPosition
       .Width = 300
       .Height = 140
    End With
Next i

dynamicControl = "listbox" & (i) 
Msgbox dynamicControl.Bottom
```

When I run my code it errors out when I am trying to set the `dynamicControl = "listbox" & 0`  and the error I am recieving is `object variable or with block variable not set`object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: You need to store the controls you have created in a collection and then just return the bottom of the last item added

Comment: I have figured it out, I can just do `Clist.Top` and because I know the size of the listboxs I can return the bottom! I should have realized this sooner but thanks for your help

Comment: you must use the `Set` keyword when assigning to an object variable, e.g., `Set dynamicControl = Me.Controls("listbox" & i)`

Answer (score -1):

---

to get your dynamic height you can use a code like this , by sending the number of clist this code is going to create them :

```
Private Sub createcontrol(num As Integer)
    Dim StartPos As Integer
    Dim WidthPos As Integer
    StartPos = TextBox1.Top + TextBox1.Height + 10
    For i = 1 To num
        Set cList = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
        With cList
            .Name = "listbox" & (i)
            .Left = 150
            .Top = StartPos
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 140
            StartPos = StartPos + .Height + 10
            Me.Width = .Width + .Left
        End With
    Next i
    Me.Height = StartPos - 8

End Sub
```

Comment: Why you disliked my answer.

Comment: it wasn't me that disliked your question! I already had a fix for this answer which I have detailed in the comment under my question. However, I will try your solution and if it works I will up vote your answer :) thanks for the answer by the way!